# How to pass parameters to URL and get response to parse

Tags: android

How to pass values to URL and parse the response?

My url is ASP.net

**"url/SomeProject/SomeApi/UserRequest/GetUserRequest/Id/userName"**

Here i want to pass **Id** and **userName** to the url. Then i get a response for that particular id. I need to parse the response and show in my activity.

Comment: refer http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/ and http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: for soap http://android.programmerguru.com/android-webservice-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after trying for one day, found the solution..

```
     String UserRequestId, LoginUserName, response;

 try {

            HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet("http://url/VirtusMobile/VirtusApi/UserRequest/GetUserRequest/"+UserRequestId+"/"+LoginUserName);
            HttpResponse httpResponse=httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity=httpResponse.getEntity();
            response=EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);


        }
```

This "response" can now be parsed..

Thanks for all for your support :)

Answer (score 0):

One of many other options [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

```
String.format("url/SomeProject/SomeApi/UserRequest/GetUserRequest/%s/%s", id, userName)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to call this piece of code in async thread and use in `doInBackground()` method.

```
private class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
     @Override
     protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
     String urlParameters = null;

    try {
            urlParameters = "& Id =" + URLEncoder.encode("1", "UTF-8")+
                    "&GameId=" + URLEncoder.encode(Integer.toString(Mojoy.pref.getInt("gameCode", 0)), "UTF-8") +
                    "& userName =" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
            log.d("urlParameters", urlParameters); 
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    String filename = “xyz”;
        File file = new File(_context.getFilesDir(), filename);
        try {

            URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
            HttpURLConnection conexion = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conexion.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            conexion.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conexion.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
                       "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            conexion.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + 
                           Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
            conexion.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");  


            conexion.setUseCaches (false);
            conexion.setDoInput(true);
            conexion.setDoOutput(true);

            //Send request
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
                  conexion.getOutputStream ());
        wr.writeBytes (urlParameters);
        wr.flush ();
        wr.close ();


            InputStream input = conexion.getInputStream();
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();  
        return "true";
        } catch (Exception e) {

            return null;
        }
     }
}
```

This code saves the response in file xyz which you can parse and do as you like.

You can get the saved file path like this:

```
String filename = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+"/xyz";
```

Hope this helps.